# Dockerfile throws error 127 when trying to run

Tags: docker, docker-image

I want to push a docker image to Heroku, there is no problem.
But when I try to access the app, I'm granted with an error message that shows:

`/bin/sh: 1: ./pocketbase: not found`

My Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PORT 8000
CMD ./pocketbase serve --https=0.0.0.0.0:$PORT --debug
EXPOSE 8000
```

[This is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieQ8a.png)

I do not find a way by myself to fix it.

Comment: Is an image of the file structure necessary? Can you write it out? There are plenty of ways to format that.
Also, how did you build your docker image?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: You're trying to run an .exe, executable for windows, on a ubuntu image. Otherwise I recommend starting up your image in interactive mode and then you take a look inside and verify that files are where they're suppose to be.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the docker-compose.yml file also other relevant code which will help the answerer.

Comment: I found the problem, indeed it is embarrassing but I tried using a .exe format for a ubuntu system. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the usage of a ubuntu system, it is not possible in this way to run a .exe program.

I simply had to use the appropriate file.